# Python subprocess with stdout redirect returning an int

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am trying to read out data from a set of print statements in a C++ program that is being run using a subprocess.

C++ code:

```
printf "height= %.15f \\ntilt = %.15f \(%.15f\)\\ncen_volume= %.15f\\nr_volume= %.15f\\n", height, abs(sin(tilt*pi/180)*ring_OR), abs(tilt), c_vol, r_vol; e; //e acts like a print
```

Python code:

```
run = subprocess.call('Name', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C++'})
data, error = run.communicate()
```

However instead of getting the data, all I am getting is a single int, the exit code, either a 0 or an error code. Of course, python then tells me "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'communicate'".

How do I actually get the data (the printf)?

Comment: `{'LANG': 'C++'}` is almost certainly wrong. The system global `LANG` should be set to a _human_ language to control localization. There is a legacy `LANG="C"` to select basically no localization support. But the `"C"` value refers to the legacy Unix C runtime, not the C language itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) just runs the command and returns its exit status (In python the exit status can be set by `sys.exit(N)` -- In other languages the exit status is determined by different means).  If you want to actually get a handle on the process, you'll need to use `subprocess.Popen`.  So, for your example:

```
run = subprocess.Popen('Name', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C++'})
data, error = run.communicate()
```

The programs exit status is now available through the `returncode` attribute.

Also, as a matter of style, I would either do:

```
run = subprocess.Popen('Name', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C++'})
data, error = run.communicate()
```

or:

```
run = subprocess.Popen('Name', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env={'LANG':'C++'})
data, _ = run.communicate()
```

Since you're not giving yourself the ability to capture stderr, you probably shouldn't pretend like you got something meaningful.